# Is there a way to change/update Release pipeline iteration numbers

Tags: azure, azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to change the Release pipeline number with version number which is divided into like 3 parts, major,minor and build. Suppose for example Release pipeline will gets updated every time as '21', '22' ... But I want to change this by reading the numbers from that nad change it to version like "1.0.0" and which keeps incrementing for each run like major, minor, build + 1.

Highlighed as yellow from the screenshot which I am trying to change.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to change/update Release pipeline iteration numbers

The answer is yes.

You could update it from the **Options** tab on the release pipeline:

[image]

The value could be `$(major).$(minor).$(rev:r)`. The value will be `1.0.1`.

Note: You need define the `major` and `minor` in the Variables tab.

[image]

> Yes $(major).$(minor).$(rev:r) will work definetely but I am trying to update my each Release build as Release-$(major).$(minor).$(rev:r) so that the Release build number should be like Release-1.0.1 . But same while updating it in the json file as version, I want to update only version from that, like 1.0.1 to manifest.json file.

You just need to simply deal with the variables with the command line task:

```
 echo $(Release.ReleaseName)

 set  TestVar=$(Release.ReleaseName)

 set MyCustomVar= %TestVar:~8,35%

 echo %MyCustomVar%
```

Comment: Ok thanks Leo. But same value can we take it inside the Releas epipeline and print it in json file or powershell script while running pipeline?

Comment: @SantoshKumar, You could use `$(Release.ReleaseName)` to get it.

Comment: Yes I have tried `$(Release.ReleaseName)` but it is giving me error. I will attach those logs here. I think inside the json file already the version format is there like "x.y.z", so I feel there is a conflict.    Logs:  **Release-1.0.3 : The term 'Release-1.0.3' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
2022-02-25T06:30:00.4109976Z program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.**

Comment: Actually as you suggested, I added for Release number iteration as `Release-$(major).$(minor).$(rev:r)`. So If I want to print the same number in the json file, I tried as you suggested `$(Release.ReleaseName)`. So it is updating as `Release-1.0.1` But in the json file I need to update the only the version number as **1.0.1**.

Comment: @SantoshKumar, So, just update the `Release-$(major).$(minor).$(rev:r)` to `$(major).$(minor).$(rev:r)` is not work for you?

Comment: Yes `$(major).$(minor).$(rev:r)` will work definetely but I am trying to update my each Release build as `Release-$(major).$(minor).$(rev:r)` so that the Release build number should be like `Release-1.0.1` . But same while updating it in the json file as version, I want to update only version from that, like `1.0.1` to manifest.json file.

Comment: @SantoshKumar, Check my updated answer.